# Oracle PL/SQL - wildcard replacements with empty strings

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

To give you a little heads up. I am fairly new to the PL/SQL world.
Most of the text below is just to give you a little context. 
Also, I have to use a function to generate the text on the fly. It is not an option to write the text into the db.

Anyway, I am working on a set of functions that will generate strings.

```
function f_nlg_concat(p_id in number) return varchar2 as
  l_id     number;
  l_text_schaden  varchar2(4000);
begin
  l_id    := p_id;
  l_text := f_nlg(l_id);
  l_text := f_nlg_replace(l_text, l_id);
end;
```

The above function is the one that concatinates all the strings. For this example I will only use one text (l_text). The l_text will be provided by the function:

```
f_nlg(p_id)
```

Now where it gets interesting is the second function:

```
f_nlg_replace(p_text,p_id)
```

This function basically queries via dynamic sql to find the right replacements for the wildcard. There are alot of wildcards.
A text might look like:

```
'I am a text with this <wildcard>.'
```

A view provides the right wildcard replacement. I am able to identify the right replacement by iterating over all the columns of the view by using this dynamic sql:

```
for cur in (SELECT atc.column_name
              FROM all_tab_cols atc
             WHERE lower(table_name) like 'v_nlg_wildcards'
               AND owner = 'ME') loop
  /*check if exist*/
  l_query1 := 'select count(' || cur.column_name ||
              ') from ME.v_nlg_wildcards nw where nw.id =' ||
              l_id;

  execute immediate l_query1
    into l_wildcard;

  if l_wildcard = 1 then
    l_query2 := 'select ' || cur.column_name ||
                ' from ME.v_nlg_wildcard nw where nw.id =' ||
                l_id;

    execute immediate l_query2
      into l_baustein;
    /*THIS IS WHERE I GOT A QUESTION*/
    l_text := replace(l_text,
                      '<' || lower(cur.column_name) || '>',
                      l_wildcard);
  else
    continue;
  end if;
end loop;
```

It works all perfect as long as there are wildcards to find. I case there is a NULL the replace wont work obviously.

But have you had any familiar cases in where you had to replace wildcards with empty strings? 
Any ideas on how to still do the replacements? 
So that there'll be no wildcards left in the text.

The whole text should still look like there is not wildcard left. The sentences are partly written that an empty replacement would fit as well.

Thank y'all in advance.

Cheers,
Sven

Comment: I think it would greatly help your question if you could start it off just by showing us sample input and output.  Then, include all these details if you think they are necessary.

Comment: Where do you have a problem? `replace('asdfghjk', 'asd', null)` returns `"fghjk"`, there is no problem with nulls.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, i found my error. Please, consider this question as answered or closed.